# EF - generate query (IQueryable) and execute with new instance of DBContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-6

I have Querybuilder class for some of my entities (chaining method) that builds and return `IQueryable<CarPricelistPrice>` or generate DTO's for my needs

example:

```
CarPriceListPriceBuilder.Create()
            .TerminIntersect(from, to)
            .OfficeId( officeId )
            .PointInTime( DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1))
            .Build()
            .ToIQueryable()
```

My Build methos generate IQueryable depending on conditions set before build method.

in CarPriceListPriceBuilder class i defined property:

```
private IQueryable<CarPricelistPrice> carPricelistPriceQuery
```

and part of my Build() method:

```
....if (carCategoryId.IsNotNull())
        {
            carPricelistPriceQuery = carPricelistPriceQuery.Where(c => c.CarCategoryId == carCategoryId);
        }

        if (dateFrom != null && dateTo != null)
        {
            carPricelistPriceQuery = carPricelistPriceQuery.Where(c => c.DateFrom < dateTo.Value && c.DateTo > dateFrom.Value);
        }....
```

so at the end of my build i have IQueryable ready to be executed to database (.ToList()) but depending of my needs i might call .Any() or add some additional filter later.

As i build this query i dont have DBContext so my question is how do i run my carPricelistPriceQuery against database or how do i attach this query to DBContext and run `.ToList()` or `.Any()` or `.FirstOrDefault()` ..?

i was reading about compiled queries delegate or storing it to `Func<context, IQueriable>` but i cant get it to work.